# Exception in lightning component when loading on mobile app web view using lightningout.js

Tags: lightning, jquery, mobilesdk, bootstrap, lightning-out

We have a custom mobile app where it loads the lightning components in hybrid web view through lightningout.js. we found an error message displayed in mobile webview for a component, it contains jquery and bootstrap elements added in it.

The component gets loaded properly in desktop browsers (as salesforce app, loading the lightning pages directly) without any issues.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHpL1.jpg)

[image]